# QUnit tests: do you avoid including HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

I use QUnit for may js testing, but I get very annoyed maintaining the fixture html so that it accurately reflects my actual page html (id, class names, etc).  I recently overhauled a page, and it was a huge pain to then have to go and change all the html in my QUnit test files.

I now try to keep all DOM interactions out of most js functions, except, for example, under an initial JQuery event.  This way I can just use QUnit to test functions that take inputs and return outputs without the need to interact with any html and have selenium take care of the DOM interaction.

Don't like:

```
const convert_val = function(val) {
    $('#id2').value(val + 1);
});

const trigger = function() {
    $('.class').on('click', function() {
        const value = $('#id1).value();
        convert_val(value);


}
```

Like:

```
const trigger = function() {
    $('.class').on('click', function() {

        const value = $('#id1).value();

        $('#id2').value(value + 1);
}
```

With the first version I can now just test `convert_val` and let selenium worry about `trigger`, where as in the second version, if I want to test `convert_val`, I have to supply qunit fixture html.  So my main question is, does anyone else
try to avoid qunit fixture html / is there a better way to go about avoiding having to maintain two sets of html?

Comment: A fairly opinion based question.  I'll just say that when I do jasmine tests, which are similar to qunit tests (both are javascript unit testing libraries), typically when I test a method, I create just enough scaffolding to make the test work.  I do not worry about it being an exact match of the page.  I leave the testing of the exact matching tests to the functional/integration tests.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm trying to get a sense of how people deal with writing html for their tests.  I'm not trying to push my method, but rather showing what I've resorted to to avoid it.